# Where do the files in Microsoft Teams end up in a meeting without channel assignment?

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

In Microsoft teams I can create meetings, these have no channel or team assignment. So they take place outside a team/channel. Where do the shared data etc. end up in such a meeting?
I see this meeting channel only under the Chat tab. If I hide the chat, how do I find it again?

Answer (score 0):

A separate meeting chat is created for Teams meeting if no channel or team is assigned to it.

You can always find it under chat section. In case you hide the chat, you can search with the meeting name and it will reappear. This functionality is same as hiding chat of a 1-1 conversation.